# Converting Data frame to time series in R

Tags: r

I currently have this data set below, but I am unsure as to how I can convert this into a time series from the data frame format that it is currently in.

I am also unsure as to how I can split this data up to create an in-sample and out-of-sample data set for forecasting.

```
      Date Observations
1  1975/01         5172
2  1975/02         6162
3  1975/03         6979
4  1975/04         5418
5  1976/01         4801
6  1976/02         5849
7  1976/03         6292
8  1976/04         5261
9  1977/01         4461
10 1977/02         5322
11 1977/03         6153
12 1977/04         5377
13 1978/01         4808
14 1978/02         5845
15 1978/03         6023
16 1978/04         5691
17 1979/01         4683
18 1979/02         5663
19 1979/03         6068
20 1979/04         5429
21 1980/01         4897
22 1980/02         5685
23 1980/03         5862
24 1980/04         4663
25 1981/01         4566
26 1981/02         5118
27 1981/03         5261
28 1981/04         4459
29 1982/01         4352
30 1982/02         4995
31 1982/03         5559
32 1982/04         4823
33 1983/01         4462
34 1983/02         5228
35 1983/03         5997
36 1983/04         4725
37 1984/01         4223
38 1984/02         4940
39 1984/03         5780
40 1984/04         5232
41 1985/01         4723
42 1985/02         5219
43 1985/03         5855
44 1985/04         5613
45 1986/01         4987
46 1986/02         6117
47 1986/03         5777
48 1986/04         5803
49 1987/01         5113
50 1987/02         6298
51 1987/03         7152
52 1987/04         6591
53 1988/01         6337
54 1988/02         6672
55 1988/03         7224
56 1988/04         6296
57 1989/01         6957
58 1989/02         7538
59 1989/03         8022
60 1989/04         7216
61 1990/01         6633
62 1990/02         7355
63 1990/03         7897
64 1990/04         7159
65 1991/01         6637
66 1991/02         7629
67 1991/03         8080
68 1991/04         7077
69 1992/01         7190
70 1992/02         7396
71 1992/03         7795
72 1992/04         7147
```

Comment: You can check `?ts` try `ts(df1$Observations, start = c(1975, 1),  end = c(1992, 4), frequency = 12)`

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more readable. You can use the `{}` icon to improve formatting.